# How to get a warning on PHP short tags when set to off

Tags: php

On almost all server where I work short tags are set to ON but for a specific project I'm using a server where they are set to OFF with PHP 5.4.45

the problem is that some of my old script use short tags, I did replace and fixed them but if I accidentally use them PHP just output the code inside HTML comments

any way to get an error or a warning?
or at least don't print them in HTML?

Comment: Why don't you replace the short tags? I guess that's easier

Comment: @modsfabio He's asking how to prevent inadvertent omissions.

Comment: Yea, but still it's easier to find them, for example using `grep` and replace them

Comment: Are server default settings the only reason to avoid short tags? Because you can tweak settings to your needs (and I think it's always a good idea, whether to enable or disable them).

Comment: @modsfabio I presume you're suggesting to implement a build task that makes the ckecks. Not a bad idea. He can probably use phpcs.

Comment: There are many ways to check the scripts before uploading them to a live server

Comment: I already made a search and replace but i may write a short tag in code, or include a file that may contain them and i don't get any error or warning, i can't edit server config

Comment: But... You can't enable short tags because you don't know how to do it, or because there's a project policy or coding standard that prohibits it?

Comment: is a project policy that prohibits it